# How can I convert a string with newlines in it to separate lines?

Tags: c#

How to convert string that have `\r\n` to lines?

For example, take this string:

```
string source = "hello \r\n this is a test \r\n tested";
```

and how can I convert that to:

```
string[] lines ;

//lines[0] = hello;
//lines[1] = this is a test;
//lines[2] = tested ;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [String.Split Method (String[], StringSplitOptions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx) like this:

```
var lines = source.Split(new [] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

This one will work regardless of whether the source is written with Windows linebreak `\r\n` or Unix `\n`.

As other answers mention, you could use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` instead of `StringSplitOptions.None` which, as the name says, removes empty strings (`" "` does not qualify for being empty, only `""`does).

Comment: You may add Mac: `\r` as well and `\x0085` for IBM (see [this note](http://www.w3.org/TR/newline)) :)

Comment: Didn't know they had `\r` but I see its only on `Mac OS <= 9` so they are properly not relevant.

Comment: @m0rb Not if you also want it to work with documents from other platforms.

Comment: @lasseespeholt: Sure, depends on were the string is created.

Comment: @m0rb True, but my solution is platform-independent (mostly, see above) and does what MS also do when they parse lines (see my other answer). But yes, if you only should go with one constant `Environment.NewLine` is definitely the way to go - but I think it´s better to cope with different files to :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to string.Split which is mentioned, you can also use [Regex.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy.aspx), but it's often more useful for more complicated split patterns.

```
var lines = Regex.Split( source, @"\r\n" );
```

Comment: I would say regex would be the better solution; if you also want to remove the space before and after the newline, or when there is no carriage return. The regex would be something like this: @" *\r?\n *"

Comment: @Andre: I agree when you're not 100% sure of the input. Then you can get a better fuzzy split with regex. If you create the files yourself, then it might not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
string[] items = source.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: He does not state that he wants to remove empty entries.

Answer (score 0):

```
string text = "Hello \r\n this is a test \r\n tested";
string[] lines = text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (string line in lines) {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(line);
}
```

You can use the [overloads of System.String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) to use a single character, array of characters, or an array of string values as the delimiters for splitting the string. The StringSplitOptions specifies whether or not to keep blank lines, or to remove them. (You would want to keep them for example if you are splitting multi-line text such as a paragraph, but would remove them in an example of a list of names)

Answer (score 0):

For clarity I have made another answer.

I have made these two extension methods:

`ReadLines` will let you read one line at the time without parsing the whole string into an array.
`ReadAllLines` will parse the whole line into an array.

In your case, you can use it like:

```
var lines = source.ReadAllLines();
```

I have taken the names from `File.ReadLines` and `File.ReadAllLines` so they should be consistent with the rest of .Net framework.

As a side note to comments on my other answer, I have checked `StringReader.ReadLine`´s code and this do take care of both `\r\n` and `\n` - but not the old legacy Mac Os etc. (shouldn't be important).

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(this string data)
    {
        using (var sr = new StringReader(data))
        {
            string line;

            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                yield return line;
        }
    }

    public static string[] ReadAllLines(this string data)
    {
        var res = new List<string>();

        using (var sr = new StringReader(data))
        {
            string line;

            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                res.Add(line);
        }

        return res.ToArray();
    }
}
```

(`ReadAllLines` could have been made with `ReadLines.ToArray` but I decided that the extra few lines of code was better than an wrapped `IEnumerable` which takes some processing time)