# Parsing text file for hexadecimal content

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I have this text file that contains approximately 22 000 lines, with each line looking like this:

`12A4 (Text)`

So it's in the format 4-letter/number (Hexdecimal) and then text. Sometimes there is more than one value in text, separated by a comma:
`A34d (Text, Optional)`

Is there any efficient way to search for the Hex and then return the first text in the parentheses? Would it be much more effective if I stored this data in SQLite?

Comment: If you need to do frequent searches on this file I would convert it into something more searchable if possible.

Comment: What's the average text length for each line? Can you load the entire file content in memory?

Comment: @Peter- searchable as in a database?
@Romain- each line has about 10 characters- 4 for hex, 2 for parentheses and 4 for text. I can load it into memory- it's only 282kb

Comment: it's just a matter of comparing the benefits to the downsides. few considerations: Is this the only data you would have to put in a DB? Is this file being queried a lot? Is this a file that changes often? Does the file require C(R)UDs? etc etc :-)

Comment: @Peter- There is pretty much no inserts, but lots of queries. It's basically only read operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example using substring and split.

```
        string value = "A34d (Text, Optional)";

        string hex = value.Substring(0, 4);
        string text = value.Split('(')[1];

        if (text.Contains(','))
            text = text.Substring(0, text.IndexOf(','));
        else
            text = text.Substring(0, text.Length-1);
```

For searching use a Dictionary.

Comment: Marked this as answer. Pretty easy to understand, no regex :), and since my file is so small (282kb), StreamReader can easily iterate through the entire file in no time at all. I'll probably explore some different options later, especially with loading data into SQLite.

Comment: Bear in mind that if you need to query several times the data you'll be reading over and over the information. Not because it easy means you have to do it.  Use a dictionary and keep that information in RAM and access it when ever you want during the program execution. See my answer for more details.

Comment: @Oscar- I agree with you. I just mean his splitting code is easy to understand, which was the main thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

That's probably < 2 mb of data.

I think you can:

1. Read the whole file
2. Split each line in key ( the hex number ) and value ( the remaining ) [Chris Persichetti](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3576266/parsing-this-text-file/3576434#3576434) answer is excellent for that
3. Store each line in a dictionary ( using the number as int , nor as string )

   ```
   d = Dictionary<int,string>
   d.put( int.Perse( key ), value );
   ```
4. Keep that dictionary in memory and then perform a very quick look up by the id

Comment: Quick question- Since my keys are hex (with numbers), doesn't that mean I can't store my key as a int?

Comment: Okay, I just decided to store it as string, string. I've implemented your solution, I'm sure I'll find some speed increases once I actually get the _other_ part of my program working!

Comment: Nope, they are actually quite parseable. I'm not sure, but probably adding "0x" would do ( at least in Java :P )

Answer (score 2):

There are elegant answers posted already, but since you requested regex, try this:

```
var regex = @"^(?<hexData>.{4}\s(?<textData>.*)$)";
var matches = Regex.Matches
              (textInput, regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreWhiteSpace 
               | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

then you parse through matches object to get whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
var lines = ...;

var item = (from line in lines
            where line.StartsWith("a34d", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            select line).FirstOrDefault();

//if item == null, it is not found

var firstText = item.Split('(',',',')')[1];
```

It works and if you want to strip leading and trailing whitespaces from `firstText` then add a `.Trim()` in the end.

For splitting a text into several lines, see my two answers here. [How can I convert a string with newlines in it to separate lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545833/how-can-i-convert-a-string-with-newlines-in-it-to-separate-lines/3545853#3545853)

Answer (score 1):

Use a StreamReader to ReadLine and you can then check if the first characters are equal to what you search and if it is you can do

```
string yourresult = thereadline.Split
                    (new string[]{" (",","}, 
                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search for the Hex value more than once, you definitely want to store this in a lookup table of some sort.

This could be as simple as a `Dictionary<string, string>` that you populate with the contents of your file on startup:

- read each line (`StreamReader.ReadLine`)
- hexString = substring of first 4 characters in line
- store the rest of the string

To find the first part, create a function that retrieves "A" from "(A, B, C, ...)"

If you can rule out commas "," in "A", you are in luck: Remove the parentheses, split on "," and return first substring.

Comment: So do you recommend I read the data every time I open the program and store it into a Dictionary, where I then search the dictionary?

Comment: That really depends on your program. I cannot really recommend anything. Just saying it "could be as simple as". It depends on how often you use the lookup table, how long it takes to load, how often it changes, how often your program runs etc. There is no "optimal solution" without answering these questions first.